# No Post matches the given query. while there are items with same slug

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

Hi I have been working on a blog app, I can create posts and view them on local host. I then hosted the blog and I get

> ***No Post matches the given query.***

I suspect the problem is with my url from what how others have solved the same problem, but it doesn't work for me.

[image: urls.py]

Views.py
[image: views.py]

[image: Template]

[image: models where there is absolute url[![][4]]][5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yy2ID.png)

Comment: Your regex for url looks OK, Are you sure your post is actually _published_?

Comment: Yes they are published and I can see them in the list view

Comment: But Your Listview is not showing only the published `posts`, as your screenshot suggests.

Comment: Post.published.all() gets only the published

Comment: I removed date  using slug  only,  no a good idea I think

Answer (score 1):

Your local database is different from your production database. Try using the the admin on your "hosted" or production database to see if there's anything there.

Depending on what kind of database you're using there are different methods to move data from you local dev environment to production

Comment: I have actually been using admin in production and I can see the posts listed but I can't see detail view.

Comment: You can see them listed here  http://omborisymons.com/articles

Answer (score 0):

Not really the answer,  just what I did.  I removed the daye from regrex and it worked